# Create azure virtual machine on Brazil

Tags: azure

i'm trying to create a azure linux virtual machine, and brazil is not in the location option.

You can see here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services that brazil is available to Virtual Machines

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure service-specific (or subscription-specific) question that needs to be addressed by Azure billing support.

Comment: you can tweet to @AzureSupport and they will get you pointed in the right direction

Comment: take a look if you're selecting virtual machines of A-series, D-series (with SSD) are not available in Brazil yet. It would help a print scree too, because I have linux vm running on Brazil's datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the table referenced you can **not** create virtual machines... You can only create Instance Level IPs and Static IPs. No virtual machine.

Hopefully this will be resolved sometime soon because I am in the same boat... My Employer has a large client as well in south America and would prefer to use this data center in Brazil rather than one of the US ones.

Comment: I sent them a ticket, they responded the same day and the made the option available for me.